# How to get 2+ million floats a second from a DB to a consumer?

Tags: performance, postgresql, elasticsearch, cassandra

A few days ago I was granted the very interesting project, of recoding the data input of a large simulation framework.

Before I accepted that task, it used an ... interesting ... file reader. That sadly didn't work.

The task is easy to describe: get up to 2+ million floats per second from a database (originally planned PostgresQL, now looking into ElasticSearch or Cassandra) into a Java proxy. Remap, buffer and feed them to a high-performance data bus.

The second part was easy enough, and the first part was standard, right? Erm, sadly wrong.

As it turned out, I somehow smashed into a brick wall of "not more than 1 Mb / s"... which is only 5% of the transfer rate needed. Yes, yes, the problem could surely be killed with more hardware, but why introduce a "built in brake", if there might be better solutions?

> A tad background on the data:
>
> A unit consists of a uuid, a type and a timeseries of values (floats). One float per minute for a whole year -> 60*24*365 = 525,600 floats.
>
> The consumer asks 150k units, for 15 time-steps a second -> 2.25 mio floats per second.
>
> We plan to pre-split the timeseries into day-batches, which seems to be a tad more manageable. Even at this rate that's about 9k*150k units = 1.35 GB of data for the buffer.

So, I tried several different ways to store and retrieve the data.

In PostgresQL the most promising approach till now is a table:

```
uuid uuid,
type text,
t1...t365 float4[]

PK is the combination of uuid and type.
```

Simple enough, I only need to SELECT tx FROM table.

Info on my testing setup: as I can't yet test with a full dataset (even faking them is painstackingly slow, at 2 sec per unit) I usually test with batches of 2k units.

Under such conditions the SELECT needs 12 seconds. According to my tests that's NOT due to transmission bottleneck (same result if I use a DB on the same machine). Which is roughly 5% of the speed I need, and much slower than I assumed it would be. **1 Mb/s???**

I haven't found any apparent bottleneck yet, so throwing more hardware at it, might even not work at all.

**Anyone knowledgable about PostgresQL an idea what's slowing it down so much?**

OK, so I tried another system. ElasticSearch might be faster, and also solve some other questions, like a nasty cluster access API I might have to add later on.

```
mapping: {
_index: timeseries_ID
_type: unit
uuid: text(keyword)
type: text(keyword)
day: integer
data: array[float]
}
```

To my surprise, this was even slower. Only 100k floats per second tops. Only 2% of what I need. Yes yes I know, add more nodes, but isn't ElasticSearch supposed to be a tad faster than Postgres?

**Anyone an idea for an ElasticSearch mapping or any configs that might be more promising?**

Now, on monday I'll get to work with my tests with Cassandra. The planned table is simple:

```
day int PRIMARY KEY,
uuid text,
type text,
data array[float]
```

**Is there a more sensible setup for this kind of data for Cassandra?**

Or does anyone have a better idea alltogether to solve this problem?

**Clarifications**

> If I do understand what you want I can't see why you are using a database at all.

Reason behind using a DB is, that the data comes from outside people, with varying IT-skills. So we need a central storage for the data, with an API as well as maybe a simple web frontend to check the integrity and clean up and reformate it into our own internal system. A database seems to work better on that front than some proprietory file system. That one could be more easily clogged and made unusable by inexperienced data contributors.

> I'm not sure it's clear on what you're trying to do here or why you seem to be randomly trying different database servers.

It's not randomly. The Postgres was a typical case of someone going: "oh but we do use that one already for our data, so why should I have to learn something new?"

The Elasticsearch approach is trying to leverage the distributed cluster and replication features. Thus we can have a central permanent storage, and just order a temporary ES cluster on our vms with replicates of the needed data. This way ES would handle all the data transport into the computer cluster.

Cassandra is a suggestion by my boss, as it's supposed to be much more scalable than Postgres. Plus it could comfort those that prefer to have a more SQLy API.

> But - can you show e.g. the query in PostgreSQL you are trying to run - is it multiple uuids but a short time-period or one uuid and a longer one?

Postgres: The simplest approach is to get all uuids and exactly one daybatch. So a simple:

```
SELECT t1 FROM table;
```

Where t1 is the column holding the data for dayset one.

For testing with my (till now) limited fake data (roughly 2% of the full set)  I sadly have to go with: `SELECT t1, t2 ... t50 FROM table`

Depending on testing, I might also go with splitting that one large select into some/many smaller ones. I'm thinking about going by a uuid-hash based split, with indexes set accordingly of course. It's all a question of balancing overhead and reliability. Nothing is final yet.

> Are we talking multiple consumers or just one?

At the start one consumer, planned is to have multiple instances of the simulation. Much smaller instances though. The 150k unit one is supposed to be the "single large consumer" assumption.

> How often are the queries issued?

As needed, in the full fledged approach that would be every 96 seconds. More often if I switch towards smaller queries.

> Is this all happening on the same machine or is the db networked to this Java proxy and if so by what.

At the moment I'm testing on one or two two machines only: preliminary tests are made solely on my workstation, with later tests moving the db to a second machine. They are networking over a standard gigabit LAN.

In the full fledged version the simulation(s) will run on vms on a cluster with the DB having a dedicated strong server for itself.

> add the execution plan generated using explain (analyze, verbose)

Had to jury rigg something with a small batch (281 units) only:

```
Seq Scan on schema.fake_data  (cost=0.00..283.81 rows=281 width=18) (actual time=0.033..3.335 rows=281 loops=1)

Output: t1, Planning time: 0.337 ms, Execution time: 1.493 ms
```

Executing the thing for real: 10 sec for a mere 1.6 Mb.

Now faking a 10k unit by calling t1-t36 (I know, not even close to the real thing):

```
Seq Scan on opsim.fake_data  (cost=0.00..283.81 rows=281 width=681) (actual time=0.012..1.905 rows=281 loops=1)

Output: *, Planning time: 0.836 ms, Execution time: 2.040 ms
```

Executing the thing for real: 2 min for ~60 Mb.

The problem is definitely not the planning or execution. Neither is it the network, as I get the same slow read on my local system. But heck, even a slow HDD has at LEAST 30 Mb/s, a cheap network 12.5 MB/s ... I know I know, that's brutto, but how come that I get < 1Mb/s out of those dbs? Is there some bandwith limit per connection? Aunt google at least gave me no indication for anything like that.

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear on what you're trying to do here or why you seem to be randomly trying different database servers. If I do understand what you want I can't see why you are using a database at all. But - can you show e.g. the query in PostgreSQL you are trying to run - is it multiple uuids but a short time-period or one uuid and a longer one? Are we talking multiple consumers or just one? How often are the queries issued? Is this all happening on the same machine or is the db networked to this Java proxy and if so by what?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`** - that will show you how long processing of the query _on the server_ takes.  [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Rather then having 365 array columns, did you try a single column using a two-dimensional array?

Comment: I'll do on monday, have no access to my workplace right now. Concerning 2D array: Yes I did: MUCH worse performance, somewhere around factor 30 iirc. Again citing from my head.

Comment: OK, added the EXPLAIN, did more testing and... it boggles me. The structure and data is trivial, according to explain it's a breeze. There is no reason for a botteneck. Still at no point do I get more than 1 Mb/s. It just doesn't make any sense. I could see being limited by a slow network, or a bad drive... but I'm worst case using 2-5% netto of the hardwares bandwith...

Comment: I think you have to look for alternative approaches. 
I.e InfluxDB - it looks capable to handle such amount of data.